# Can an Exchange Online distribution group be configured to forward mail to it's users alternate email?

Tags: active-directory, email, microsoft-office-365, distribution-lists

I've been trying to figure out how to create a distribution list containing personal email addresses for all our staff. This could be done by adding each staff member as a mail contact with their personal email address and adding those mail contacts to a distribution group - but it seems silly to have both a user and a mail contact for each staff member.

Active Directory Online has a field for "alternative email address". Is there a way to use either that or a custom user field to populate a distribution group and then have email sent to that group be forwarded to it's members alternate address/the address in a custom field for each user?

Comment: Sadly you have answered your own question. Its a dumb way to do it but the only way I have seen.

Comment: I'd avoid doing that completely, with spf and dmarc,  you're sure to have some issues relaying that email.

Answer (score 0):

Some alternative approaches I can think of:

1. Enable forward rules on the mailbox, you can specify that only mail from certain senders will be forwarded and you can still keep a copy in the mailbox.
2. Transport rules could be configured to forward messages to alternate addresses.
3. Use MS Flow or Zappier to create a workflow that forwards messages to personal addresses.
4. Setup a listserv, or sign up for a free mail chimp account and manage contacts there.